# Excelsior aude?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, latin-to-english-translation, motto

I came across the phrase "*excelsior aude*" which seems to translate to courageously onward and upward? Is this accurate and would be it better reversed to *aude excelsior* or *excelsior aude*? Any thoughts? Perhaps there's a more elegant way to phrase this?

Answer (score 6):

*Audeo* is 'I dare'

*Aude*  is the imperative, an exhortation, 'Dare,' or '**Be daring**.'

*Excelsus,* is 'noble,' 'lofty.'

*Excelsior* is 'more noble' and describes the person you are speaking to when you tell them to be daring. It is also the single-word motto on the banner of an absolutely fearless, honourable, daring knight in a poem by [Longfellow](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44631/excelsior-56d223cb4e6fa); "A youth, who bore, 'mid snow and ice, A banner with the strange device, Excelsior!"

All the best mottoes have a double meaning; in this case it lies in the word *Excelsus* which can also be a past participle meaning 'When you have been overcome, When you have been beaten,...'
So the subtext is: when you have been overcome, that is the time to be daring.

A more predictable version would be *Excelsius aude.* 'Be more nobly daring.'
But that would lack both the subtlety and the moral courage of your version.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. Would it read better as Excelsior Aude or the other way around (Aude Excelsior)?

Comment: Latin verse was not comfortable with two vowels between words: in poetry it's used to describe torrent, muddle; and there's disagreement about whether they garbled the vowels *Audyexelsior* or elided *Aud'excelsior.* But whatever feels right to you is fine.

Comment: If you want to find out more about adjacent vowels in separate words, type or paste  elision  in the Search box (towards the left in the top black band); and then try  synizesis